# How to spread arguments from params

Tags: go, slice

I have this:

```
    LS : func(s ...string) []string {
        return []string{s...}
    },
```

I just want to populate the slice from a list of arguments. Do I really have to loop over the arguments and append them to the slice?

the error is:

[image]

Comment: just return `s`, its already slice from attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variadic parameter is a slice. Quoting from [Spec: Passing arguments to ... parameters:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

> If `f` is [variadic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) with a final parameter `p` of type `...T`, then within `f` the type of `p` is equivalent to type `[]T`.

So you just need to return it:

```
LS : func(s ...string) []string {
    return s
},
```